# Display image if field is true

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have a table called user_badges and a field called badge1 with the default value written **"locked"** when a user unlocks the badge the field is updated to **"unlocked"**

What I want is the script to check the value in the field badge 1 in the table  **WHERE $username = $_SESSION['username'];** and display the image of the badge located in a folder on my site.

I have an idea on how to go about it but not sure how to fully execute this.

```
//Connect to database
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("host","username","password");
mysql_select_db("database_name");
?>

if field (field_name) from table (table_name) value= unlocked
echo/display image from (images/badges/fanaticbadge.png)

else echo/display (images/badges/locked.png)
```

Is this possible? Thanks for any assistance !

Comment: good start, now keep going ...

Comment: If you can avoid it, please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo). Please see [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9). [Here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC) for PDO. Also see [Why shouldn't I use `mysql` functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/ycnmO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$q = "SELECT badge1 FROM user_badges WHERE username='{$_SESSION['username']}' LIMIT 1";
$r = mysql_query($q);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
$badge1 = $row['badge1'];

if($badge1 == "unlocked") {
 print "image if user has unlocked the badge";
  } else {
 print "image if user hasn't unlocked the badge";
}
```

Comment: Wow that works great! Thanks a lot! could I also add $q->execute(array($username)) ?